# Email converted to attachment

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, email-studio

One of our subscribers occasionally receives daily bulletin as an attachment. The whole sending process is automated and HTML code looks fine.

What an issue it can be?

Comment: Can you post your code? How big is your list? Can you share more info about your automation?